# Text to Image in ReactJS/NextJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I want to convert some text to a image in ReactJS. And the image should have a link which can be shared.
Eg:- Spotify's lyrics share system.

I have tried nothing. I searched some libraries but got nothing.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/Milan-960/Img-Generator

Comment: I am surprised you got nothing when you searched. I have just tried 'converting html to an image in react' and there are several ideas, including here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few different ways you can convert text to an image in React:

Using the Canvas API: The Canvas API provides a way to draw text onto a canvas element using the fillText method. You can then use the toDataURL method to convert the canvas to an image data URL that you can use as the source for an  element.
Ex :

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = '30px Arial';
ctx.fillText('Hello, world!', 10, 50);
const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Or you can use third-party library like html2canvas which is directly convert your DOM element or HTML string to an image.